# is there any ways to avoid blinking component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query

```js
import { useState } from "react"

import { Box, List, ListItem } from "@chakra-ui/react"
import { Skill } from "api-models"
import axios from "axios"

import SearchInput from "./components/SearchInput"
import { useOutsideClick } from "./hooks/useOutsideClick"
import { useSearchList } from "./hooks/useSearchList"
import { useSearchQuery } from "./hooks/useSearchQuery"

const Search = () => {
  const [isFocused, setIsFocused] = useState(false)
  const inputRef = useOutsideClick<HTMLInputElement>(() => setIsFocused(false))

  const { keyword, onSearch } = useSearchList("")
  const { data: searchList } = useSearchQuery<_Skill, Skill[]>(keyword, {
    queryFn: async () => {
      const { data } = await axios.get("/api/v1/skills")
      return data
    },
    select: (data) => {
      return data.skills
    },
  })

  return (
    <Box w="200px">
      <SearchInput
        value={keyword}
        inputRef={inputRef}
        onChange={onSearch}
        onFocus={() => setIsFocused(true)}
      />
      <List>
        {searchList?.map((item) => (
          <ListItem key={item.id}>{item.name}</ListItem>
        ))}
      </List>
    </Box>
  )
}

export default Search
```

```js
export const useSearchQuery = <T, U>(
  value: string,
  options?: SearchOptions<T, U>,
) => {
  return useQuery({
    queryKey: ["search", value],
    enabled: value.length > 0,
    ...options,
  })
}
```

I want to make Search input with autocomplete behind.
when input event fire, value is changing so queryFn is executed.
but returned data is changing undefined -> real data,
so autocomplete section is empty -> full, it causes blinking.
is there a good way to avoid that?
I want to remain previous state while value is changing like google